# Gulp Compiling Issues with gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I am having two issues in compiling Sass using Gulp currently. Firstly, I set 777 permissions in my "/Library/Ruby/Gems" directory to free up some permissions errors I was getting. I'm now receiving a warning each time I run Gulp, stating the following:

```
gulp-ruby-sass: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 in PATH, mode 040777
```

Second, things seem to halt in terms of Sass compilation when Gulp runs into some of the "@import" declarations in my primary SCSS file. Namely, I get the following errors:

```
gulp-ruby-sass: error ./screen.scss (Line 4: File to import not found or unreadable: normalize.
Load paths:
/private/var/folders/cq/_pg4s6qn59q1q5fyy5681rd00000gn/T/gulp-ruby-sass/bower_components/compass-breakpoint/stylesheets
/private/var/folders/cq/_pg4s6qn59q1q5fyy5681rd00000gn/T/gulp-ruby-sass/bower_components/susy/sass
/private/var/folders/cq/_pg4s6qn59q1q5fyy5681rd00000gn/T/gulp-ruby-sass/bower_components/normalize-scss
/private/var/folders/cq/_pg4s6qn59q1q5fyy5681rd00000gn/T/gulp-ruby-sass)
```

These load paths look incorrect...I've installed these components via Bower for this project specifically, so it almost seems like I need to tell Gulp/NPM to look in my project folder instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found an article detailing someone's trouble with the exact same issue. https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/75 I'm loading in several separate Bower components as an array in the LoadPath for Gulp-Ruby-Sass in Gulp. For some reason, the paths aren't relative to the gulpfile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this question was just me doing a whole lot of talking to myself, but I'll share my findings with the world nonetheless.

Turns out, this is a known issue with the gulp-ruby-sass package. See:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/pull/80#issuecomment-49531932

Paths specified in the "loadPath" option in my gulpfile were not relative to the gulpfile's location in the project I was working with, so it wound up looking for some Bower components in a folder where it shouldn't have, for example:

```
/private/var/folders/cq/_pg4s6qn59q1q5fyy5681rd00000gn/T/gulp-ruby-sass/bower_components/compass-breakpoint/stylesheets
```

**I found that, by prepending *process.cwd()* to each of my file paths, they would become relative.**

If you take a look at the GitHub link I added a few lines above, you'll notice this is simply a temporary workaround until this fix is implemented into the master branch of gulp-ruby-sass, so this advice will become irrelevant at some point in the near future.

Hope this helps anybody that was in a similar, puzzled situation.

*** EDIT ***

As for the permissions warning I was getting for gulp-ruby-sass, it turned out I just needed to run `sudo chmod -R 775 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0` to recursively change the permissions in the Gems directory.